# Using FileSystemWatcher for Copy-Item doesn't work if multiple files added

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I need to watch the folder D:\test and copy the new coming files to the folder D:\output.

- it sometimes works fine and copy the first few coming files successfully then it just stop copying.
- sometimes it doesn't work at all.
- when it works, it works only if I add one file to the D:\test, but if I added more than one file (copy 2 or 3 files and paste them in  folder D:\test) the `Copy-Item` doesn't work afterward.

Here is my code:

```
$folder = 'D:\\test'
$filter = '*.*'                            
#$dest = 'D:\\output'
$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true             
    NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
    Copy-Item $path "D:\output" -Force -Verbose 
}
```

Comment: `$folder = 'D:\\test'` should be `$folder = 'D:\test'`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result. Just noticed that the line 'Write-Host' always works, but 'Copy-Item' does not , and when adding multiple files, the 'Write-Host' works for one file only, I guess the first received one. @Ansgar Wiechers